# A more efficient way of streaming video on the pi

Tags: linux, unix, pi, motion

I am a surfer/kitesurfer and i live in the UAE. I'm trying to build a basic weather station that can provide wind and webcam details for a spot that is in a remote location. I am using a pi4 1GB and i am almost ready to install the station on site. My skills are fairly basic but this is where i am at:

1. pi4 runs ddns so it's dynamic address is accessible remotely with port forwarding - done
2. weewx uploads wind and weather info from the sensor to windguru - this is on track and will be done by the end of the week when a final part arrives
3. motion eye provides the video stream of camera 1 and camera 2 - done and visible from outside the LAN
4. Run apache/mysql/wordpress to provide a basic interface for people to check the info from their browser - almost done.

Now, regarding point 3... i am noticing that this is crippling the pi. Running nmon i can see each camera is utilising 110% of the CPU per camera. That is with minimal video streaming settings and a 1 fps rate. With both cameras running the pi is almost inaccessible through vnc or ssh and it gets very hot - i need to keep restarting it as it freezes.

I don't need a live stream, i'd be happy with an image every 30 seconds. Even if i disable video streaming and use the still image capture, 'motion' is still costing the CPU 110% per camera just to monitor it. Is there a better piece of software that i can be using?

I tried to edit sudo nano /etc/motion/motion.conf hoping to reduce the fps that motion uses to initialize the device but it doesn't affect the CPU usage.

Important to note, my camera is connected via IP and motion is connected to the device via RTSP://

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,
Sean.

Answer (score 0):

Try UV4L and RPi_Web_Cam_Interface as alternatives to Motion.
RPIWCI is nicely documented at this site
https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface
The preview mjpeg stream from RPIWCI can be found at the URL http://YourPiIP:Port/cam_pic_new.php
You can set the quality and size using the 'camera control' bar at the bottom of the preview/control page found at yourPiIP:80/html/ (change the port to your forwarding port)
There is also the opportunity to use a timelapse function that might provide a different route to get a 1fps jpeg stream, I have not tried this.
I am currently streaming the preview at 1024x720 ~15fps compression quality 30% to several devices on my local network and the Pi4 is utilising only about 10%  CPU.

Other comments.....
Have you tried setting the GPU memory split on the Pi to 1024 
Also have you tried the command 'top' at the linux prompt to see what processes are using all the CPU, raspimjpeg uses between 2 and 3 % on my Pi4.

Hope this helps, Heath.

Comment: Thanks Heath. That is amazing that it is using so little CPU. To be honest i have temporarily given up on a live stream from the camera because i could not get UV4L to attach the RTSP feed as a local camera - i tried and tired, then gave up. What i'm doing now is using ffmpeg to to take a screenshot. That is contained in a script which crontab runs every 5 minutes. That results in a new picture every 5 minutes which is saved into my /var/www/html/images/ folder and then using apache users access the index.html which ultimately sees the image. Not perfect, but easy on cpu and network.